# Адаптация сайта под мобильное устройство

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, друзья. Мне нужен совет, а лучше человек, который конкретно мне скажет, что именно я делаю не так. Я написал сайт, но меня беспокоит его отображение на мобильных устройствах. Разработкой сайта занимаюсь не так давно, поэтому прошу помощи. Код выложу ниже

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\html\project1\CSS\style_about.css">
            <body class="courses">
                <style>
                    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@700&family=Lobster&display=swap');
                  </style>
                <header class="header">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="header_wrapper">
                            <div class="header__logo">
                                <a href="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\html\project1\index.html" class="logo_link">
                                    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\html\project1\icon\logo.png" alt="something" class="logo">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <nav class="header_nav">
                                <ul class="header_list">
                                    <li class="header_item">
                                        <a href="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\html\project1\index.html" class="header_link">Главная</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header_item">
                                        <a href="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\html\project1\courses.html" class="header_link">Курсы</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header_item">
                                        <a href="#!" class="header_link">Гайды</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header_item">
                                        <a href="#!" class="header_link">Консультации</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <div class="main_container">
                    <h1 class="title">Видео-лекции, подкасты, чек-листы, практические задания, рекомендации и просто масса полезной информации.</h1>
                    <div class="courses__1">
                        <dl>
                            <dt>Курс «Половое воспитание для родителей».</dt>
                            <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\html\project1\icon\new_photo\IMG_4259.JPG" alt="my__photo" class="my__photo">
                                <dd class="info__course1"><i>Общие знания о том, что такое половое воспитание. В каком возрасте, какими словами и на какие темы нужно говорить с детьми: от самого рождения до совершеннолетия. Вы сможете узнать, что включает в себя половое воспитание, какие темы важно проговаривать с детьми и как.</i></dd>
                        </dl>
                        <h2 class="description">Курс включает в себя 13 видео-лекций, размещенных в закрытом телеграмм-канале. Продолжительность каждой лекции от 15 до 35 минут. Вы можете сами выбирать, когда и какую лекцию просматривать.</h2>
                        <h3 class="course__content">Содержание курса:</h3>
                        <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\html\project1\icon\new_photo\IMG_4260.JPG" alt="content_course" class="photo_course1">
                        <ol class="count__lections">
                            <li>Введение. Коротко о том, что такое половое воспитание. Что оно в себя включает и чем отличается от сексуального образования. Почему половое воспитание необходимо и какую роль в развитии ребенка оно играет.</li>
                            <li>Половое воспитание для детей до 5 лет. Психологические особенности детей этого возраста. Какие термины использовать родителям для обозначения половых органов с детьми в этом возрасте. Основные действия родителей в этот период – практические рекомендации.</li>
                            <li>Детская мастурбация. Когда возникает и как проявляется. Почему ее не надо бояться и предотвращать. И когда все же необходимо обращаться к специалистам.</li>
                            <li>Половое воспитание в возрасте от 5 до 10 лет. Возрастные психологические особенности детей в этот период. Что интересует мальчиков и девочек в этот период и как с ними об этом говорить.</li>
                            <li>Физиологические изменения в теле ребенка в подростковый период. Как подготовить ребенка к этому. Поговорим о том, как объяснить появление волос на теле, запах пота, прыщи и многое другое. А также о том, как приучить ребенка к личной гигиене.</li>
                            <li>Менструация. Как разговаривать об этой теме с девочками и мальчиками. Как устроены половые органы девочек. И все о средствах личной гигиены в период менструации</li>
                            <li>Первые полюции. Особенности полового созревания с юношей. Как и о чем говорить?</li>
                            <li>Контрацепция. С какого возраста и как эту тему нужно обсуждать с детьми. Поговорим о плюсах и минусах различных видов контрацепции. А также рассмотрим виды ЗППП и ИППП.</li>
                            <li>Первый секс. Как и когда говорить с ребенком именно о сексе. Какие термины нужно использовать при разговорах не тему секса. Нужно ли говорить подросткам, что взрослые люди занимаются сексом для получения удовольствия?</li>
                            <li>Умение сказать «нет». Всё о том, как помочь ребенку ценить свое тело и свои эмоции, выстраивать личные границы не только в сексе, но и во взаимодействии с другими людьми.</li>
                            <li>Как реагировать родителям, если ребёнок говорит о том, что ему нравятся представители своего пола?</li>
                            <li>Сексуальные интроекты. Как часто взрослые случайными фразами могут негативно повлиять на сексуальность ребенка.</li>
                            <li>Безопасность в интернете. О чем важно говорить с ребенком, перед его регистрацией в социальных сетях. Какие опасности может нести человек за аватаркой.</li>
                        </ol>
                        
                        <h3 class="desc">Также вы можете приобрести доступ только к 1 из интересующих вас лекций всего за 400 рублей.</h3>
                        <button class="price__course">Купить курс сейчас!</button>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <h1 class="footer__title">Подписывайтесь на мои социальные сети</h1>
                    <div class="block__link">
                        <a href="https://instagram.com/elena_ne_mudraya?igshid=MzRlODBiNWFlZA==" class="footer__link" target="_blank">
                            <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\html\project1\icon\instagram.svg" alt="instagram" class="tiny__icon">
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://t.me/elena_ne_mudrayaa" class="footer__link" target="_blank">
                            <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\html\project1\icon\telegram.svg" alt="telegram" class="tiny__icon">
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://youtube.com/@elena_ne_mudraya?si=XNU7INeSR0psJ0pP" class="footer__link" target="_blank">
                            <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\html\project1\icon\youtube.svg" alt="youtube" class="tiny__icon">
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://dzen.ru/id/6125aea743c86f50be7123b0" class="footer__link" target="_blank">
                            <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\html\project1\icon\yandex.svg" alt="yandex" class="tiny__icon">    
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                 
                
            </body>
        </head>
    </html>

@font-face
  {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  src: url("/fonts/Play/static/PlayfairDisplay-Bold.ttf");
  }

h1{
    font-family: 'Caveat';
}

.courses{
    background-color: #F9D3D3;
    
    height:100%;
    display: block;
    max-width:1700px;
    line-height:1;
    font-size:14px;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -moz-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
}



.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #9D9292;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    z-index:10;
    opacity: 80%;
    height: 56px;
}

.logo{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.header_wrapper{
    width: 1700px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.header_list {
    padding-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
}
.header_item {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.header_item:last-child{
    margin-right: 50px;
}
.header_link {
    color: #63433E;
    font-family: Playfair Display, Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header_link:hover, .header_link:focus, .header_link:active{
    opacity: .70;
}

.main_container{
    color: #63433E;
    display: block;
    width: 1170px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
}

.title{
    max-width: 75em;
    margin-top: 100px;
    color: #63433E;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Caveat';
    font-size: 40px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
    padding-bottom: 3em;   
}



.info__course1{
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 700px;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding-left: 10em;
}


.courses__1:hover .info__course1{
    animation: anim 1s forwards;
    visibility: visible;
}

dl{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes anim {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

dt{
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 10px;
}
dt::first-letter{
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #eb8698;
}

.my__photo{
    position: absolute;
    left: 60em;
    width: 31.25em;
    height: 43.75em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 80%;
}
.description{
    color: #63433E;
    font-style: italic;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30em;
}

.course__content{
    padding-top: 5.5em;
    
}
.course__content::first-letter{
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #eb8698;
}

.photo_course1{
    width: 31.25em;
    height: 43.75em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: 35em;
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    
}
.photo_course1:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.count__lections{
    
    color: #843b30;
    text-shadow: rgb(144, 37, 137) 1px 0 6px;
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 1.5;
    top: 70em;
}

.desc{
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.price__course{
    
    font-family: 'Caveat';
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 4em;
    margin-bottom: 7em;
    margin-left: 5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgb(144, 37, 137);
    box-shadow: 0 0px rgb(144, 37, 137) inset;
    transition: .1s ease;
    
}
.price__course:hover { 
    background: rgb(5, 1, 5); 
}
.price__course:active {
    background: rgb(144, 37, 137);
    box-shadow: 0 0px rgb(0, 0, 0) inset;
}
.footer{
    display: block;
    height: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #fafaff;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.footer:hover{
    opacity: 90%;
}

.footer__title{
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.tiny__icon{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    
}

.block__link{
    
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 25em;
}

.footer__link{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: У вас stylesheet ссылается на локальный файл на вашем компьютере. Каким образом мобильное устройство должно  видеть стили? И картинки. Я уже не говорю о body внутри head - пока что получите основы.

Comment: Тег body случайно там оказался, исправил. А на какой файл должен ссылаться stylesheet?

Comment: Не вижу исправления

Comment: В общем, тут невозможно дать ответ, потому что у вас там микс и каша из скопированных невесть откуда стилей. Вам надо привести HTML к стандартному (чтобы стили были бы внутри head, body не внутри head и т.д). Пути до файлов желательно указывать относительными. Что касается "мобильности" - у вас в стилях есть display: inline-block; .header_wrapper {
    width: 1700px; - это все мешает адаптивности, так как задает абсолютную ширину. Короче. я вам советую пока азы изучить, а то здесь налицо видно полное непонимание технологии на самом базовом уровне.

Comment: @void https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1549900/%d0%94%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-body Помоги, пожалуйста