# Длина блока body

Tags: html, css

Друзья, всем привет. Я только познаю верстку, поэтому комменты, типа "учи сначала основы и так далее", пожалуйста, не пишите. Я знаю, что мне еще учиться и учиться. Вопрос у меня связан с длиной блока body. Суть в том, что контентная часть этого блока значительно больше, чем длина, которая отображается в панели разработчика гугла, из-за чего блок footer находится не совсем там, где нужно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать и что делать?

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  /* добавим плавность переходов для всех элементов страницы*/
}

body {
  max-height: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #373737;
  background: #e49999;
}

header:after,
.container:after,
footer:after,
.widget-posts-list li:after,
#subscribe:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.container_main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(223, 119, 119);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  width: 9em;
  height: 4em;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}


/* меню */

#menu {
  float: right;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#menu a {
  color: #111;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px;
}

#menu a:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
}

#menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}


/* кнопка переключения меню, появляющаяся при ширине 768px */

.nav-toggle {
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: rgb(144, 37, 137);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-toggle span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  left: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
}

.nav-toggle span:before,
.nav-toggle span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
}

.nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

.nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Caveat';
}

.first_course {
  height: 20em;
  background: url("../icon/new_photo/IMG_4259.JPG");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.first_course dt {
  font-family: 'Caveat';
  font-size: 3.5em;
}

.first_course dd {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-family: 'Caveat';
  font-size: 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #714141 75%, #ad4141 25%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.contain_course {
  margin-top: 1em;
  color: #714141;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-family: 'Caveat';
}

.contain_course::first-letter {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: rgb(223, 119, 119);
}


/*color: #c900ae;*/

.points_course {
  color: #323232;
  font-family: 'Caveat';
  font-size: 1.7em;
  background: url('../icon/new_photo/IMG_4260.JPG');
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.point_10:hover {
  color: aqua;
}

.point_11:hover {
  color: aqua;
}

.point_12:hover {
  color: aqua;
}

.point_13:hover {
  color: aqua;
}

.price_course {
  padding-top: 5em;
  color: #714141;
}

.price_course h2 {
  font-family: 'Caveat';
  font-size: 4em;
}

.price_one_course {
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.price_one_course h3 {
  font-family: 'Caveat';
  font-size: 2em;
}

.givemecourse {
  margin-top: 2em;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  font-size: 15px;
  top: 185em;
  left: 8em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(144, 37, 137);
  box-shadow: 0 -3px rgb(144, 37, 137) inset;
  transition: .1s linear;
}

.givemecourse:hover {
  background: rgb(5, 1, 5);
}

.givemecourse:active {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 3px rgb(0, 0, 0) inset;
}

footer {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #3C3D41;
  color: white;
}

.footer-col {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
  float: left;
}

.footer-col a {
  color: white;
}

.footer-col:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

.social-bar-wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.social-bar-wrap a {
  margin-right: 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.social-bar-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.link_icon {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Курсы, полезные материалы и многое другое о детях, половом воспитании и сексе</title>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@700&family=Lobster&display=swap');
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS\style_courses.css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic|Playfair+Display:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="container">
      <a class="logo" href="">
        <img src="icon\logo.png" alt="logo">
      </a>
      <div class="nav-toggle"><span></span></div>

      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Курсы</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Гайды</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Консультации</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container_main">
    <h1 class="title">Видео-лекции, подкасты, чек-листы, практические задания, рекомендации и просто масса полезной информации.
    </h1>
    <div class="first_course">
      <div class="name_course">
        <dl>
          <dt>Курс «Половое воспитание для родителей».</dt>
          <dd class="info__course1"><i>Общие знания о том, что такое половое воспитание. В каком возрасте,
                                какими
                                словами и на какие темы нужно говорить с детьми: от самого рождения до совершеннолетия. Вы
                                сможете
                                узнать, что включает в себя половое воспитание, какие темы важно проговаривать с детьми и
                                как.</i>
          </dd>
          <dd>Курс включает в себя 13 видео-лекций, размещенных в закрытом телеграмм-канале. Продолжительность каждой лекции от 15 до 35 минут. Вы можете сами выбирать, когда и какую лекцию просматривать.
          </dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
      <div class="container_course">
        <h2 class="contain_course">Содержание курса: </h2>
        <div class="points_course">
          <ol>
            <li>Введение. Коротко о том, что такое половое воспитание. Что оно в себя включает и чем отличается от сексуального образования. Почему половое воспитание необходимо и какую роль в развитии ребенка оно играет.</li>
            <li>Половое воспитание для детей до 5 лет. Психологические особенности детей этого возраста. Какие термины использовать родителям для обозначения половых органов с детьми в этом возрасте. Основные действия родителей в этот период – практические
              рекомендации.</li>
            <li>Детская мастурбация. Когда возникает и как проявляется. Почему ее не надо бояться и предотвращать. И когда все же необходимо обращаться к специалистам.</li>
            <li>Половое воспитание в возрасте от 5 до 10 лет. Возрастные психологические особенностей детей в этот период. Что интересует мальчиков и девочек в этот период и как с ними об этом говорить.
            </li>
            <li>Физиологические изменения в теле ребенка в подростковый период. Как подготовить ребенка к этому. Поговорим про том, как объяснить появление волос на теле, запах пота, прыщи и многое другое. А также о том, как приучить ребенка к личной гигиене.</li>
            <li>Менструация. Как разговаривать об этой теме с девочками и мальчиками. Как устроены половые органы девочек. И все о средствах личной гигиены в период менструации.</li>
            <li>Первые полюции. Особенности полового созревания с юношей. Как и о чем говорить?</li>
            <li>Контрацепция. С какого возраста и как эту тему нужно обсуждать с детьми. Поговорим о плюсах и минусах различных видов контрацепции. А также рассмотрим виды ЗППП и ИППП.</li>
            <li>Первый секс. Как и когда говорить с ребенком именно о сексе. Какие термины нужно использовать при разговорах не тему секса. Нужно ли говорить подросткам, что взрослые люди занимаются сексом для получения удовольствия?</li>
          </ol>
          <div class="point_10">
            <p>10. Умение сказать «нет». Всё о том, как помочь ребенку ценить свое тело и свои эмоции, выстраивать личные границы не только в сексе, но и во взаимодействии с другими людьми.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="point_11">
            <p>11. Как реагировать родителям, если ребёнок говорит о том, что ему нравятся представители своего пола?
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="point_12">
            <p>12. Сексуальные интроекты. Как часто взрослые случайными фразами могут негативно повлиять на сексуальность ребенка.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="point_13">
            <p>13. Безопасность в интернете. О чем важно говорить с ребенком, перед его регистрацией в социальных сетях. Какие опасности может нести человек за аватаркой.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="price_course">
          <h2>Цена курса 4000 рублей</h2>
          <button class="givemecourse">Купить курс</button>
        </div>
        <div class="price_one_course">
          <h3>Также вы можете приобрести доступ только к 1 из интересующих вас лекций всего за 400 рублей.
          </h3>
          <button class="givemecourse">Купить лекцию</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="footer-col"><span>Елена Сидельникова © 2023</span></div>
      <div class="footer-col">
        <div class="social-bar-wrap">
          <a class="link_icon" title="Instagram" href="https://instagram.com/elena_ne_mudraya?igshid=MzRlODBiNWFlZA==" target="_blank">
            <img src="icon\instagram.svg" alt="">
          </a>
          <a class="link_icon" title="Telegram" href="https://t.me/elena_ne_mudrayaa" target="_blank">
            <img src="icon\telegram.svg" alt="">
          </a>
          <a class="link_icon" title="YouTube" href="https://youtube.com/@elena_ne_mudraya?si=XNU7INeSR0psJ0pP" target="_blank">
            <img src="icon\youtube.svg" alt="">
          </a>
          <a class="link_icon" title="Dzen" href="https://dzen.ru/id/6125aea743c86f50be7123b0" target="_blank">
            <img src="icon\yandex.svg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-col">
        <a href="mailto:admin@yoursite.ru">Написать письмо</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script>
    $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      $('#menu').toggleClass('active');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Уберите `height: 20em` с элемента `.first_course`. Зачем там вообще фиксированная высота?

Comment: Для установки высоты маленькой фотографии

Comment: Это устанавливает высоту для всего блока и контент блока получается больше установленной высоты, в этом и есть Ваша проблема.

Comment: Да, сейчас разобрался. Спасибо большое, что откликнулись!